# Problema con DataTable y caracteres especiales

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

Alguno sabe por qué mi datatable no reconoce los carácteres especiales, por ejemplo cuando agrego un usuario Iván, en el listado sale como Iv�n  sin embargo en la base de datos si sale como Iván correctamente.

Así es mi código, primero agrego los cdns de DataTable, luego la tabla y al final el script

```
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/simple-datatables@latest/dist/style.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="card mb-4">
 <div class="card-header">
  <i class="fas fa-table me-1"></i>
   Atletas inscritos
 </div>
 <div class="card-body">
  <table id="datatablesSimple">
   <thead>
     <tr>
       <th>Nombre</th>
       <th>Nombre de la academia</th>
       <th>Categoría</th>
       <th>Sexo</th>
       <th>Cinturón</th>
     </tr>
  </thead>
  <tfoot>
     <tr>
       <th>Nombre</th>
       <th>Nombre de la academia</th>
       <th>Categoría</th>
       <th>Sexo</th>
       <th>Cinturón</th>
     </tr>                
  </tfoot>
   <tbody>
     <?php ListarAtletasController(); ?>
    </tbody>
   </table>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/simple-datatables@latest" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="../js/datatables-simple-demo.js"></script>
```

El script se ve así

```
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', event => {
    // Simple-DataTables
    // https://github.com/fiduswriter/Simple-DataTables/wiki

    const datatablesSimple = document.getElementById('datatablesSimple');
    if (datatablesSimple) {
        new simpleDatatables.DataTable(datatablesSimple);
    }
});
```

Comment: Agrega `<meta charset="utf-8">` dentro de tu etiqueta `<head>`. Además, Prueba imprimiendo tus variables de **php** utilizando `utf8_decode($var)` o `utf8_encode($var)` según sea el caso

Comment: Muchas gracias la opcion,de utf8_encode($var) me ha funcionado